# Finding duplicates and their indices in an array in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I want to find the duplicates in an array and their indices using bash.
For example, I have this array:

```
arr=("a" "b" "c" "a" "c")
```

In this case, "a" is a duplicate at index 0 and 3, and "c" is also a duplicate at index 2 and 4. 
I am currently using two nested loops but I find it too slow especially when it is a large array.
Is there a better, more efficient way of doing this in bash?

Thank you!

Comment: I once posed the same question, but for associative arrays.  Does this solve your issue? [Inverting an associative array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506891)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk, feeding array elements as input:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" |
  awk '{ elmnt[$0]= ($0 in elmnt? elmnt[$0] FS:"") NR-1 }
  END{ for (e in elmnt) print e, elmnt[e] }'
a 0 3
b 1
c 2 4
```

---

for new requirement (save each result into a shell variable):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" |
  awk -v q="'" '{ elmnt[$0]= ($0 in elmnt? elmnt[$0] FS:"") NR-1 }
  END{ for (e in elmnt) print e, q elmnt[e] q }' OFS='='
a='0 3'
b='1'
c='2 4'
```

save above command output to a file, then export that file using `export varfile` (`varfile` is just a filename), so all the variables will be exported as a shell variables.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Is there a way to save each result in a bash variable?

Comment: @lilek3 see the second part of the answer, maybe that can help you? see also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an associative array to check if the value has already been seen, without resorting to a linear scan every time:

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=("a" "b" "c" "a" "c")
declare -A values=()
for v in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [ "${values["x$v"]+set}" = set ]; then
        echo "value '$v' is duplicate"
        break
    fi
    values["x$v"]=1
done 
unset values
```

How fast that will be compared to just dumping the values for awk to process probably depends on the problem size. Shells aren't fast, especially Bash is slow.